# Estimating population divergence time with a single mitochondrial marker

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, phylogenetics

Is it possible to estimate population divergence time with a single mitochondrial marker?

Here is additional information for my specific case:

- Mitochondrial marker: Cytochrome Oxidase Subunit 1 (COI)
- Molecular clock rate for COI for my taxon of interest: 1.29-1.96 % per million year
- Age of the taxon: ca. 2.69 million years
- Number of individuals per population: 10